# Apache rewrite to 404 except for matched query

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to handle logically simple operation, but apache rewrite does not handle my website's query string requests. I heard it does not do it eventually. Still cannot understand its regex syntax.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\?category=([a-z])$ // WHY DO I NEED THIS?
RewriteRule ^!(?category=[a-z]+|?do=[a-z]+)$ [R=404,L,NC]
```

Goal is to send the client to 404 for any query NOT matching /?category=[a-z]+ and /?do=[a-z]+. It would be much better if it's possible to load patterns from the text file.

The Apache documentation is poor and Google does not help as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include the query string inside `RewriteRule`. It is matched in `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# For js & css
# Normally this would be done with:
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# But since you might have files here you're trying to put a 404 on, 
# we'll do it differently, matching css & js files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*)\.(css|js)$

#Conditions check if either query param is missing (negated with !)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !category=([a-z]+) 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !do=([a-z]+)

# Rewrite anything not matched by the querystring conditions above...
# Edit -- was missing the rewrite target ( - )
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Now I'm having troubles allowing /js/ and /styles/ RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} !styles/([a-z0-9]+) RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} !js/([a-z0-9]+)

Comment: @Radio I had an upvote, and then someone came along to downvote. (Above 1000 rep, you can see the up/down counts)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I don't see it! It's was 0/0 from beginning. I don't like the other answer reporting Apache documentation as plenty good. =))

Comment: I optimized it to:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\?category=([a-z]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\?do=([a-z]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/styles/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/adm1n/$

But this one

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$

Does not work with $ at the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7497/discussion-between-radio-and-michael)

Comment: @Radio What's the point of `RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$`?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you . I can't find any documentation on how to properly match ^/$ in RewriteCond.